# PHP - Add link to a URL in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, function, url

I have a function that will add the `<a href>` tag before a link and `</a>` after the link. However, it breaks for some webpages. How would you improve this function? Thanks!

```
function processString($s) 
{
    // check if there is a link

    if(preg_match("/http:\/\//",$s))
    {
        print preg_match("/http:\/\//",$s);


        $startUrl =  stripos($s,"http://");

        // if the link is in between text
        if(stripos($s," ",$startUrl)){
            $endUrl = stripos($s," ",$startUrl);
        }
        // if link is at the end of string
        else {$endUrl = strlen($s);}

        $beforeUrl = substr($s,0,$startUrl);
        $url = substr($s,$startUrl,$endUrl-$startUrl);
        $afterUrl = substr($s,$endUrl);

        $newString = $beforeUrl."<a href=\"$url\">".$url."</a>".$afterUrl;

        return $newString;
    }

    return $s;
}
```

Comment: The regex is a little sloppy, but 99% of my input will have correct URLs if any

Comment: What webpages does it break for?

Comment: At the beginning you test agains https also, but later you omit the "s". Dont know, if this cause this error, because I also dont know, which pages are broken ;)

Comment: Sorry, I removed the [s] from the regex. How could I include functionality for strings such as "www.google.com", or "https:www.example.com" ?

Comment: "www.google.com" is going to be harder to parse. you need a long regex just to accommodate all TLDs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
function processString($s) {
    return preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[\w\-\.!~#?&=+\*\'"(),\/]+/','<a href="$0">$0</a>',$s);
}
```

Comment: I think a "=" is missing: it fails when the url contains get parameters. I just added it after the "&" and now it works:

`preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[\w\-\.!~?&=+\*\'"(),\/]+/','<a href="$0">$0</a>',$s)`

Comment: You forgot about addresses with # inside - so more correct version is `preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[\w\-\.!~#?&=+\*\'"(),\/]+/','<a href="$0">$0</a>',$text)`

Comment: I just edited the answer to reflect these two additions.

Comment: Do not forget to add the 'u' modifier if your string may contains utf8 characters

Comment: I add one more char "%". As result: '/https?:\/\/[\w\-%\.!~#?&=+\*\'"(),\/]+/','<a href="$0">$0</a>'

Answer (score 1):

It breaks for all URLs that contain "special" HTML characters. To be safe, pass the three string components through htmlspecialchars() before concatenating them together (unless you want to allow HTML outside the URL).

Answer (score 1):

```
function processString($s){
  return preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $s);
}
```

Found it [here](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=36992)

Comment: The same scenario I need it in Jquery/Javascript. Can anyone help ?