# How do I auto convert an url into a hyper link in PHP?

Tags: php, function

I have a script that outputs status updates and I need to write a script that automatically changes something like `www.example.com` into a hyper link in a chunk of text like Twitter and Facebook do. What functions can I use for this in PHP? If you know a tutorial please post it.

Comment: What is an "href link?" Are you talking about [the shebang for Googlebot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/)?

Comment: @Matt Ball: Probably `<a href="…">…</a>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$string = " fasfasd  http://webarto.com   fasfsafa";

echo preg_replace("#http://([\S]+?)#Uis", '<a rel="nofollow" href="http://\\1">\\1</a>', $string);
```

Output:

```
 fasfasd  <a rel="nofollow" href="http://webarto.com">webarto.com</a>   fasfsafa
```

Comment: What about https?

Comment: It will work only in same cases, but not on links like `https://example.org/folder/?query#hash`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to replace the url with a link. Look at the answers on this thread: [PHP - Add link to a URL in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217406/php-add-link-to-a-url-in-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

Great solution!

I wanted to auto-link web links and also to truncate the displayed URL text, because long URLs were breaking out of the layout on some platforms.

After much fiddling around with regex, I realised the solution is actually CSS - [this site](http://perishablepress.com/wrapping-content/) gives a simple solution using CSS white-space.

Comment: You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer and include the essential parts of the solution from that page here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working Function

```
function AutoLinkUrls($str,$popup = FALSE){
if (preg_match_all("#(^|\s|\()((http(s?)://)|(www\.))(\w+[^\s\)\<]+)#i", $str, $matches)){
    $pop = ($popup == TRUE) ? " target=\"_blank\" " : "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches['0']); $i++){
        $period = '';
        if (preg_match("|\.$|", $matches['6'][$i])){
            $period = '.';
            $matches['6'][$i] = substr($matches['6'][$i], 0, -1);
        }
        $str = str_replace($matches['0'][$i],
                $matches['1'][$i].'</xmp><a href="http'.
                $matches['4'][$i].'://'.
                $matches['5'][$i].
                $matches['6'][$i].'"'.$pop.'>http'.
                $matches['4'][$i].'://'.
                $matches['5'][$i].
                $matches['6'][$i].'</a><xmp>'.
                $period, $str);
    }//end for
}//end if
return $str; }
```

Comment: This looks like it almost works, but those <xmp> tags are messing things up for me.