# alter form input to add <A> tags before adding to database

Tags: mysql, html

I want to have a 'website' input field which I want to be stored as a hfef link in a mysql table, but I can't  expect users to add the href tags themselves I need it to be automatic. I guess it must be some thing to do with the input value but I don't know what what exactly. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add http:// if it's not exists in the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-its-not-exists-in-the-url) (1st Google hit) or try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217406/php-add-link-to-a-url-in-a-string (second Google hit)

Comment: Just add the `<a>` string dynamically... (either with JavaScript before submitting the form, or with your server-side language before storing the string in the DB).

Comment: Have whatever scripting language you're using to put the value into the database alter it first. Check whether there's an <A> tag at the beginning, and if not, add it. Then check whether there's an </A> tag at the end and if not, add that.

Comment: no, sorry, what I mean is the user types in example.com but it gets stored as <a href>example.com</a>

Comment: you're not storing your URL straight from HTML to MySQL. In your back-end code (PHP, .Net, Python etc) just wrap your `example.com`  with an `<a href="">...</a>`

Comment: I tryed: $website=<a href>$_POST_['website']</a> but got a parse error I'm not sure about the correct syntax with parenthesis here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`website = "<a href=\"" . $_POST['website'] . "\">The Site</a>";`

Should work for you or

`website = "<a href=\"" . $_POST['website'] . "\">" . $_POST['website'] . "</a>";`

If you want the user's input as both the text and the href part.