# Automatically parse text to link in PHP

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

So, what i want is to parse normal text to link

but if the text is link then it should not be parsed again

for example: `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>` should not be parsed again to be `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a></a>`

That's all

Comment: What does the text look like? Is it HTML or is it plain text to start off with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4217406/2028547

Comment: @VladJula-Nedelcu none, i don't know much about regex

Comment: @Husman plain text and gonna be changed to HTML

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to strip out all the HTML href tags to start off with. Then you have a plain document and you can convert every url to a  tag.

Comment: but of course the other HTML elements in the same document will be missing too

Comment: not if you just strip out the "<a href=" and "</a>" parts only

Comment: but the other links with different URL and link text will be error

Comment: no, a link looks like this "<a href='http://www.test.com'>some text</a>" you just need to find and remove "< href='" and "'>some text </a>" and leave the url there. Your second script will then convert all URLs to links

Comment: but i want the link where the URL and the link text different keep to be like that

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function TextLink($string)
{
   if($string[0] != "<")
   {
      echo "<a href=\"http://www.".$string."\">".$string."</a>";
   }
}
?>

Call with TextLink('$string');
```

Comment: the text ia a blog post, so the link is inside the other text

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want then. 
You have a blog post like "blah blah blah blah HYPERLINKTHISWORD blah blah blah blah"? 

Could you maybe give an example as the answer I gave works for your questions example.

Comment: yeah, like that. here is an example: "i have a site, the URL is http://mysite.com, please visit it!"