# Find URL in a text, ignoring html tags

Tags: regex, url

I got the following text/html :

```
Hello ! You should check this link : http://google.com
And this link too : <a href="http://example.com">http://example2.com</a>
```

I want a regexp to catch URLs in my text to replace them by a `<a>`. I got the following regexp :

```
var REG_EXP = /[^">]((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)[^"<]/gi;
```

But my regexp also catch `http://example.com` and `http://example2.com`. And i don't know how to refine it to avoid this.

Comment: I don't get it. You just want to surround the google url by `<a />`, but not the example2, right?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287144/need-a-good-regex-to-convert-urls-to-links-but-leave-existing-links-alone

Comment: Perhaps this is not a good use case for regexp:  see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Looks like lorenzo.marcon is right, my question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217452/1795220. Definitely having HTML like `<a href="http://example.com">http://example2.com</a>` is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This could suit your needs:

```
(?<!href=")(http://[a-z0-9]++(?:[.-:/?&=][a-z0-9]+)++)(?!</a>)
```

Be aware that the url pattern I used is very simple and permissive:

```
http://[a-z0-9]+(?:[.-:/?&=][a-z0-9]+)+
```

- `(?<!href=")` means "not preceded by `href="`"
- `(?!</a>)` means "not followed by `</a>`"
- `++` is called a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

Just replace the matches by `<a href="$1">$1</a>` as in [this example](http://regexr.com?35bas).

Don't expect too much from regex when trying to solve this kind of job, this is not what they are done for.