# PHP preg replace url in string with html href

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have found alot of functions that answers my question in the top, but most of theese functions have problems. The best what I have so far found is this one

```
//Replace links with http://
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" class=\"chatlink\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">\\2</a>", $ret);

//Replace links without http://
$ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" class=\"chatlink\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">\\2</a>", $ret);
```

The problem is, this doesn't replace the url, if it is in the middle of the text. For example, it does not replace text in string something like this:

*"Small text http://www.google.com , and some more text."* 
It works fine if the link is not in the the middle of the text, but in new line.

And secondly I need to make sure, if in string already is html href link, that it doesn't replace the url again.

`<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>`

`<a href="<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>"></a>`

That would be it. Would be amazing if someone could help me, Im just not too good with preg_replace function.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217406/php-add-link-to-a-url-in-a-string

Comment: Make yourself more clear by just putting input strings(all possible), what code you have applied on them and what your expected outcome for each input.

Comment: I can't understand exactly what the problem is. Because what you've just described is working fine on that regex. I ran your regex and it replaced the link in that text. And also, it didn't replaced the url again.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help, there was &nbsp; before link, thats why it didn't work. Sorry for my mistake.